# Babel texture scale and setting on face

Tags: babylonjs

I'm creating a DynamicTexture with a canvas that has a loaded image drawn onto it and I'd like to apply it to only one face of the box, ensuring that my loaded image is scaled to the texture properly.

I've found some examples on how to apply sprites to faces but the method I'm using a slightly different so it's proving to be confusing: https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#ICZEXW#8

So far I've factored the following:

```js
// Create the box
const frame = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateBox("FrameBase", { height: 1.9, width: 1.95, depth: 0.05, updatable: true }, scene);
// Create textures and mat with 900 resolution
const textureResolution = 900;
const frameTexture = new BABYLON.DynamicTexture("FrameTexture", textureResolution, this._scene, true);
const textureContext = frameTexture.getContext();
const frameMaterial = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("Mat", this._scene);                 
frameMaterial.diffuseTexture = frameTexture;
const img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
img.onload = function () {
    textureContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    frameTexture.update();
};
// The following image has a width of 900px
img.src = 'imagepath.jpg';

mouldingMaterial.diffuseColor = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 0.5, 0.5);
mouldingMaterial.diffuseTexture = frameMaterial;
```

It seems that I can scale the imagepath.jpg to the size of the Box using the textureResolution property on DynamicTexture. If I change this it seems the material doesn't fill the space...it seems correlated to the width of the image I've loaded.

Assuming I'm correct, that issue is resolved but the texture is being applied to all sides of my box. I'd like to apply it to one side then specify colours for the remaining ones.